Proof that separation of variables leads to a complete basis of wave function in spherical coordinates
In griffith's introduction to quantum mechanics (chapter 4), there is an analysis of the stationary states of a particle given a potential function $V(r)$ that only depends on the radial distance $r$, and a wave function $\Psi(r,\theta,\phi,t)$ is assumed to be composed as $\Psi = R(r)\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi)\phi(t)$.
I know from a previous question that we can prove that this gives a complete basis of all solutions using the spectral theorem, at least for the one-dimensional case. However, I can't really see how to prove this. For example, one of the equations we come up with (when spelled out) is:
$$\left(2r\frac {\partial }{\partial r} + r^2 \frac {\partial ^2}{\partial r^2} - r^2(V-E)\frac {2m}{\hbar^2}\right)R=l(l+1)R$$
But if I'm not mistaken, the $2r\frac {\partial }{\partial r}$ part is not Hermitian, so the spectral theorem doesn't apply?
Is the proof of complete basis written out somewhere, so I can clarify this?

Does this answer your question? Why does separating variables in the spherically-symmetric TISE work? ...your question seems a bit confused. If the Hamiltonian is self-adjoint, it admits a complete orthonormal (generalized) basis as eigenvectors. Stepping back from your example, you can always write $H=H_1+H_2$ where both $H_1$ and $H_2$ are not hermitian; but this does not matter...

@TobiasFünke, It doesn't really, because the answers to that question basically jus say "it's an ansatz and it turns out to work", they don't prove why it works. Regarding: " If the Hamiltonian is self-adjoint, it admits a complete orthonormal (generalized) basis as eigenvectors". Afaict, this tells us that the eigenfunctions of $H$ give us a complete basis for solutions of the form $\Psi=\phi(t)*\psi(r,\theta,\phi)$, because the separation equation for that gives us $H\psi=E\psi$. But the separation equation for $\psi=R(r)Y(\theta,\phi)$ gives us a different equation, namely ...

Sorry, I don't get what you mean. The answers and comments discuss to which extend separation of variables work. In the comments I gave some references, too. If you need further clarification of an answer, consider to leave a comment there. But your question seems to be a duplicate.

@TobiasFünke $\left(2r\frac {\partial }{\partial r} + r^2 \frac {\partial ^2}{\partial r^2} - r^2(V-E)\frac {2m}{\hbar^2}\right)R=l(l+1)R$, which is another equation of the form  $Q\psi=AR$ for $Q=\left(2r\frac {\partial }{\partial r} + r^2 \frac {\partial ^2}{\partial r^2} - r^2(V-E)\frac {2m}{\hbar^2}\right)$. So afaict, if we want to show that separating into $\psi=R(r)Y(\theta,\phi)$ and finding the solutions of that form still gives us a complete basis, we have to show that $Q$ is a hermitian operator, not that $H$ is hermitian. Am I wrong about this?
